# Setting locale for current session

Tags: linux, localization

I would like to change LC_MESSAGES locale var for current session like so:

```
LC_MESSAGES="fr_FR.utf8"
```

but it seems to not work:

```
user@debian:~$ cat w1.txt 
cat: w1.txt: Brak dostępu
user@debian:~$ LC_MESSAGES="fr_FR.utf8"
user@debian:~$ cat w1.txt 
cat: w1.txt: Brak dostępu # no change!
```

When i do it "per program":
`LC_MESSAGES="fr_FR.utf8" cat w1.txt` it works:

```
cat: w1.txt: Permission non accordée
```

Shouldn't change made in the current session (LC_MESSAGES="fr_FR.utf8") be taken into account when running cat command?

Answer (score 0):

You need to `export` environment variables in order for them to apply to programs you start:

```
ts@xenon:~> cat doesnotexist.txt
cat: doesnotexist.txt: Datei oder Verzeichnis nicht gefunden
ts@xenon:~> export LC_MESSAGES="fr_FR.utf8"
ts@xenon:~> cat doesnotexist.txt
cat: doesnotexist.txt: Aucun fichier ou dossier de ce type
```

Comment: Ok but why setting "LANG" variable DOES work WITHOUT `export`?

Comment: It doesn't. It may just appear so to you because LANG is already exported somewhere in your profile. Try undoing that with `unset LANG` and re-test.